# android building failed on bitbucket pipeline during lintVital

Tags: android, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Recently, I configured Bitbucket Pipeline to build the android apk.

Here is the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    QA:
      - step:
          name: Test Release
          size: 2x
          caches:
            - gradle
          script:
            - echo "$KEYSTORE_FILE_BASE64" | base64 -d > android-signing-keystore.jks
            - export GRADLE_OPTS='-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -Dorg.gradle.parallel=false -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.configureondemand=true'
            - ./gradlew clean assembleStageRelease appDistributionUploadStageRelease
```

Actually, it worked fine before.
But the building had been failing from last week.

Here is the error log.

```
> Task :app:lintVitalStageRelease FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalStageRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
            > Connection reset
```

If I run the command on my local machine, it works fine now...

```
> ./gradlew clean assembleStageRelease appDistributionUploadStageRelease
```

What problem??

---

I updated the `build.gradle`.

Before:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

After:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

But it same results...

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spooncast:lintVitalStageRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':spooncast:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
            > Connection reset
```

Comment: Does your company own the bitbucket build machine?  If so, check if some firewalls have been changed.  It seems like the machine can't reach https://jcenter.bintray.com anymore.

Comment: No, we are using the cloud bitbucket